# Instagram authentication error

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

When i go to instagram authentication url, such us ( https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=00d8a10aab774c1c9a674471ca261ccc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fspider13.net%2Finst&response_type=code&scope=basic+comments+relationships+likes )
instagram api redirect me to main page ( https://instagram.com/ )

Answer (score 1):

It is an instagram bug, it should be fixed now. I had contacted Instagram earlier, they confirmed its their issues and they are rolling back, here is their response:

> We’re aware of the issue and reverting the change, this should be
>   fixed within the next 30 minutes.